# Software center won't start 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, software-center, lts

After checking the site, I tried to remove it and install it again. Terminal says 'it's already the newest version'.
I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: This is a very low quality question. Please provide necessary information including how you tried to remove and re-install it. This way, nobody can help

Comment: I did : sudo apt-get remove software-center (then auto remove) and after sudo apt-get update and then sudo apt-get install software-center

Comment: share any update related to the problem as an update in the question. Please run: `sudo apt-get purge software-center` and then try to update

Comment: I did it : purge then update. Software-center still not opening. Thanks anyway

Comment: Now I tried to launch it through Terminal : software-center. The answer was : the program 'software-center' is not installed. You can install it by typing : sudo apt install software-center. I did. And it now starts only through Terminal. The icon is not launching it

Comment: @Christine, now re-install it: run `sudo apt install software-center`.  After that, it should work fine.